# Pandas - Duplicate rows with phone numbers based on type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe is in the following format:

| name | phone | other_phone |
| --- | --- | --- |
| alice | (111) 111-1111 | (222) 222-2222, (333) 333-3333 |
| bob | (444) 444-4444 | (555) 555-5555, (666) 666-6666 |
| colin | (777) 777-7777 | (888) 888-8888 |
| david | (999) 999-9999 | NaN |

I want to split the `other_phone` column on the comma (if there is one) and duplicate rows such that the output is:

| name | phone | phone_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| alice | (111) 111-1111 | work |
| alice | (222) 222-2222 | other |
| alice | (333) 333-3333 | other |
| bob | (444) 444-4444 | work |
| bob | (555) 555-5555 | other |
| bob | (666) 666-6666 | other |
| colin | (777) 777-7777 | work |
| colin | (888) 888-8888 | other |
| david | (999) 999-9999 | work |

The overall goal is to prevent there being multiple phone numbers in a single row. How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will (obviously) take a little bit of reshaping! Specifically we'll need to create 2 separate `DataFrames` that have the necessary "phone" and "name", then your `"phone_type"` is derived based on what `DataFrame` you belong to.

1. The easiest part is to create a `work_phones` DataFrame, since that's already nicely represented by the data.
2. A little bit trickier will be to split out the "other_phone" data. We'll need to split these values and then explode them to vertically stack all of the values. Finally we'll need to reach back into the source `DataFrame` to grab the correct `"name"`s for each phone number.
3. Finally, we stick these 2 parts on top of each other via `pd.concat`!

Assuming your `DataFrame` is stored in a variable called `df`...

```py
import pandas as pd

# easy
work_phones = df[['name', 'phone']]

# little trickier
other_phones = (
    df['other_phone'].str.split(',')
    .explode()
    .to_frame('phone')
    
    # grab the correct name from the original DataFrame
    .join(df['name'])
)
```

Now that we have our parts, we just need to stack them on top of each other with `pd.concat` and a few arguments.

```py
final = (
    pd.concat([work_phones, other_phones], names=['phone_type'], keys=['work', 'other'])
    .reset_index(level=0)

    # sort the data to match OP output
    .sort_values(['name', 'phone_type'], ascending=[True, False])
)

print(final)
  phone_type   name            phone
0       work  alice   (111) 111-1111
0      other  alice   (222) 222-2222
0      other  alice   (333) 333-3333
1       work    bob   (444) 444-4444
1      other    bob   (555) 555-5555
1      other    bob   (666) 666-6666
2       work  colin   (777) 777-7777
2      other  colin   (888) 888-8888
3       work  david   (999) 999-9999
3      other  david              NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
import timeit
from pandas import DataFrame
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['alice', 'bob', 'colin', 'david'],
                   'phone': ['111', '444', '777', '999'],
                   'other_phone':
                   ['222, 333', '555, 666', '888', np.nan]})
print(df)
"""
    name phone other_phone
0  alice   111    222, 333
1    bob   444    555, 666
2  colin   777         888
3  david   999         NaN
"""

df = (
    df.join(
        df.pop( 'other_phone').str.split(',',expand=True)
        .stack()
        .reset_index(level=1,drop=True)
        .rename( 'other_phone')
        
        )
    
    )
print(df)
"""
    name phone other_phone
0  alice   111         222
0  alice   111         333
1    bob   444         555
1    bob   444         666
2  colin   777         888
3  david   999         NaN
"""
workfones = df[['name','phone']]
print(workfones)
"""
    name phone
0  alice   111
0  alice   111
1    bob   444
1    bob   444
2  colin   777
3  david   999
"""
homefones =  df[['name','other_phone']].rename(columns={'other_phone':'phone'})
print(homefones)

"""
    name other_phone
0  alice         222
0  alice         333
1    bob         555
1    bob         666
2  colin         888
3  david         NaN
"""
res = pd.concat([workfones, homefones], names=['phone_type'], keys=['office', 'home'])
   
print(res)

"""
              name phone
phone_type               
office     0  alice   111
           0  alice   111
           1    bob   444
           1    bob   444
           2  colin   777
           3  david   999
home       0  alice   222
           0  alice   333
           1    bob   555
           1    bob   666
           2  colin   888
           3  david   NaN

"""

res1 = (res.reset_index(level=0) )

print(res1)
"""
phone_type   name phone
0     office  alice   111
0     office  alice   111
1     office    bob   444
1     office    bob   444
2     office  colin   777
3     office  david   999
0       home  alice   222
0       home  alice   333
1       home    bob   555
1       home    bob   666
2       home  colin   888
3       home  david   NaN
"""
res2 = res1.sort_values(by=['name','phone_type'])
print(res2)
"""
 phone_type   name phone
0       home  alice   222
0       home  alice   333
0     office  alice   111
0     office  alice   111
1       home    bob   555
1       home    bob   666
1     office    bob   444
1     office    bob   444
2       home  colin   888
2     office  colin   777
3       home  david   NaN
3     office  david   999
"""

res3 = res2.reset_index(level=0).drop('index', axis=1)
print(res3)
"""
   phone_type   name phone
0        home  alice   222
1        home  alice   333
2      office  alice   111
3      office  alice   111
4        home    bob   555
5        home    bob   666
6      office    bob   444
7      office    bob   444
8        home  colin   888
9      office  colin   777
10       home  david   NaN
11     office  david   999
"""
```